# Local dataset in Federated learning: client side, is the local update performed on a different subset of the local dataset each round?

Tags: server, client, federated-learning

I was wondering if in a Federated Learning approach I need to split the local dataset in a number of batches equal to the number of communication rounds.
Otherwise I need to update locally on the whole local dataset each round.

Building a federated learning model

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what you want to do. Federated learning is not a fixed method but a flexible approach that changes from solution to another and architecture to another i will try to make it clear by giving examples.

In Google keyboard for example they collect data in real-time so in each round there will be new data so in this case they are probably using the whole data for the update.

In another use-case you may have a huge local dataset and it takes ages to retrain the model locally so in this case you can train a subset in each round to reduce computation power and time needed to retrain the model.

Finally Federated leaning still have lot of challenges use it when it is really an obligation otherwise just adopt the normal centralized approach to train your model :)